# Angular Web App and Firebase Cloud Messaging

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a problem with my Angular web app working with Firebase Cloud Messaging if I run it on my local appache webserver and hope you can help.

I have a angular web app served on a web server in my LAN.
I have implemented the Firebase web app cloud messaging and everything works fine when I test my app on localhost:4200 which is the Angular development server.
I can receive the message so I show it in my app and if the app is closed a popup shows on firefox that I have received the message.
Can you please help why when I deploy my app to my LAN web server it does not work?

As I need to send message within my LAN, I need to save the Token to be used by cURL.
When the app running on localhost:4200, my php url can get the token and save it on my server for future use however, when the app is running on my apache server on LAN, the token value saved on my server is "undefined".

I read somewhere the firebase only works on HTTPS, however, as my local server does not have the FQDN address, I don't know how to get it working.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I tried to enable the SSL on my server and point the root documents to the folder I have my app.
Because I am subscribing to MQTT service in my app, it says it's not secure... so cannot run the app.

Is the concept right or I have to maintain it the other way?

Comment: No one even bother to reply?
I thought I can get the good result here specially from Firebase support when they mentioned that we should ask for help here!!!!

Interesting....

Comment: Please keep in mind this is a voluntary website; we are not paid to assist you. The key to getting good answers is to craft clear questions which include code samples demonstrating the issue. Your question isn't clear and doesn't contain code demonstrating the issue. Please take a moment and review [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Update and clarify your question and we'll take a look!

Comment: Thanks for your time for replying.
I think it is clear, the notification system works fine if you run it on local server (ng serve) and does not work if you deploy to Apache server not using the SSL and FQDNS....

I try to see if I can demonstrate it here anyway...